# Trouble understanding how to use lambda to sort dict

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, lambda

I am trying to sort this dictionary.

```
d = {'FNP': ['0.02', '0.02', '0.02', '0.02'],
     'TestName': ['Test1205', 'Test1206', 'Test1207', 'Test1208'],
     'eno': ['0', '0', '0', '0'],
     'GRE': ['0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00'],
     'TPS': ['78.00', '45.00', '73400', '34.00'],
     'id': ['1', '1', '1', '1']}
```

What I am trying to do is sort based on TPS and output the name wrt sorted values. Here TPS[0] corresponds to TesTName[0]. I want to sort Testname when TPS is sorted. 
Expected output:

```
d = {'TestName': ['Test1208','Test1206','Test1205','Test1207'],
     'TPS':['34.00', '45.00', '78.00', '73400']
```

This is what I have so far: `sorted(d['TPS'],key=lambda d:d)`

How do I ensure that `Testname`s are interchanged as well when I sort `TPS`?

Comment: So you want to sort the both the values of Testname and TPS? Also what happened to the other keys?

Comment: I'm guessing 73400 comes *after* 78.00. Or there's a typo somewhere.

Comment: `d` **isn't** a `defaultdict(list)`, it's just a regular dictionary—so please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a functional solution. The trick is to use `enumerate` to extract indices, remember to convert to `float` for sorting, and use `itemgetter` with multiple arguments to extract the correct order.

```
from operator import itemgetter

idx, _ = zip(*sorted(enumerate(d['TPS']), key=lambda x: float(x[1])))

res = {k: itemgetter(*idx)(d[k]) for k in ('TestName', 'TPS')}

{'TestName': ('Test1208', 'Test1206', 'Test1205', 'Test1207'),
 'TPS': ('34.00', '45.00', '78.00', '73400')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the `TPS` list sorted *numerically*, as opposed to lexically (alphabetically by value of each string element in it):

```
from pprint import pprint

d = {'FNP': ['0.02', '0.02', '0.02', '0.02'],
     'TestName': ['Test1205', 'Test1206', 'Test1207', 'Test1208'],
     'eno': ['0', '0', '0', '0'],
     'GRE': ['0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00'],
     'TPS': ['78.00', '45.00', '73400', '34.00'],
     'id': ['1', '1', '1', '1']}

d['TestName'] = sorted(d['TestName'])
d['TPS'] = sorted(d['TPS'], key=float)

pprint(d)
```

Output:

```
{'FNP': ['0.02', '0.02', '0.02', '0.02'],
 'GRE': ['0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00'],
 'TPS': ['34.00', '45.00', '78.00', '73400'],
 'TestName': ['Test1205', 'Test1206', 'Test1207', 'Test1208'],
 'eno': ['0', '0', '0', '0'],
 'id': ['1', '1', '1', '1']}
```

Note that the `TestName` list was already sorted.

Comment: You don't need a lambda at all here: `d['TPS'] = sorted(d['TPS'], key=lambda value: float(value))`. You can just write this: `d['TPS'] = sorted(d['TPS'], key=float)`

Comment: @hughdbrown: So very true...answer updated. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @jpp's solution, if you want a sorted version of all the lists in the original dict in your new dict, you can zip each data list with the original TPS, sort the tuples and create your new data list from the sorted data:

```
original_tps = [float(t) for t in d['TPS']]
sorted_d = {}

for k, v in d.items():
    sorted_d[k] = [x for tps, x in sorted([(t, e) for t, e in zip(original_tps, v)])]


print(sorted_d['TPS'])
# ['34.00', '45.00', '78.00', '73400']                                                                                                    
print(sorted_d['TestName'])
# ['Test1208', 'Test1206', 'Test1205', 'Test1207']
# ... similarly other lists are sorted
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a `Record` namedtuple to hold each individual record, then sort easily and coerce back to a dict of lists if you need it.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Record = namedtuple("Record", "FNP TestName eno GRE TPS id")

def extract(d, keys=None):
    if keys is None:
        keys = ["FNP", "TestName", "eno", "GRE", "TPS", "id"]
    records = [Record(*vals) for vals in zip(*map(d.get, keys))]
    return records

def transform(records):
    records.sort(key=lambda r: float(r.TPS))

def load(records, keys=None):
    if keys is None:
        keys = ["FNP", "TestName", "eno", "GRE", "TPS", "id"]
    d = {k: [getattr(record, k) for record in records] for k in keys}
    return d

d = {'FNP': ['0.02', '0.02', '0.02', '0.02'],
     'TestName': ['Test1205', 'Test1206', 'Test1207', 'Test1208'],
     'eno': ['0', '0', '0', '0'],
     'GRE': ['0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00'],
     'TPS': ['78.00', '45.00', '73400', '34.00'],
     'id': ['1', '1', '1', '1']}
records = extract(d)
transform(records)
new_d = load(records)
```